# How to fix Structure navigation in CP?

Tags: structure

After playing with structure, the navigation tree was broken.

[image]

Unforchently we don't have a DB backup. Any advice how to fix it?

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probable that some entries were deleted from the system, but still they still in structure exp_structure table.

**One-step solution:**

```
DELETE FROM exp_structure WHERE entry_id not IN ( Select entry_id from exp_channel_titles )
```

**Two-step solution** (if u want to validate results):

1. Find missed records:

   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(entry_id) as entry_ids  FROM 
   exp_structure WHERE entry_id NOT IN (Select entry_id from exp_channel_titles)
2. Delete missed records, using results of the first query in next query (instead of **XXXXXXXX**)

   DELETE FROM exp_structure WHERE entry_id IN ( **XXXXXXXX** )

Answer (score 2):

This is from duplicate ordering values. Run our debug mode: http://buildwithstructure.com/documentation/debug_mode_for_page_data/

Comment: Thanks, Travis! Max solution helps me this time, but next time I will try to activate debug mode.

Comment: RTFM. Always. Sorry - I missed this debug option. Next I will also use debug mode:)